# ASP Core 3.1 API with EF Core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm very interested by [the new filtered feature in EF core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#filtered-include) . I updated my entity framework with Nuget however I still can't use Where after Include.

Is it because my APIP is developed in NET Core 3.1?

[image]

Thank you for your help

**Edit :**

This is my csproj file:
[image]

Comment: Could you include your package reference for EF (Located inside your .csproj file) ? Have you tried restoring packages and rebuilding?

Comment: You can now see my .csproj file. I didn't try restoring packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because GrowerPayee is not a collection.
Code below works fine, but try to filter the Setting and you will have the same problem

```
public class Organisation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public Setting Setting { get; set; }
}

public class Setting
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid OrganisationId { get; set; }
    
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Db : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new Db())
        {
            var organisations = db.Organisations
                .Include(x => x.Locations.Where(l => l.Name.Contains("ABC")))
                .Where(o => o.Name.Contains("OOO"))
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think you just found my problem! Do you know if there is a way to filter on GrowerPayee? Or in Setting in your example?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I have already submitted a feature request to the team
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21751

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope they will add this feature. In the meantime I need to find a workaround :/

Comment: and you can upvote the request on the github project to add the feature too :)

Comment: I don't know if you'll see that message but I found out that we can do something like that:

`var queryTest = _context.LedgerEntries.Where(x => x.GrowerPayee.CropYear == cropYear);
queryTest = queryTest.Include(x => x.GrowerPayee);
var LedgerEntries = await query.ToListAsync();`

Comment: this will filter ledger entries that you might not want, ie: get all ledger entries with year >= 2000 and include growerpayee if cropyear is >= 2015, in my example I expect growepayees to be null if the cropyear is <2015 but still retrieve ledgerentries